# rename file after file upload

Tags: java

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {


         ExternalContext extContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
              File result = new File(extContext.getRealPath("//admin//images") + "//" + event.getFile().getFileName());
           // File result = new File("D:\\Netbeans Project\\mcGrawLibPro\\mcGrawLibPro-war\\web\\item", event.getFile().getFileName());
              File bg = new File(extContext.getRealPath("//admin//images")+"//macback.png");
            try {




                    bg.renameTo(new File(extContext.getRealPath("//admin//images")+"//bg.png"));
                    File f1 = new File(extContext.getRealPath("//admin//images") + "//macback.png" );
                    result.renameTo(f1);



                //System.out.println(f1);
                System.out.println(result);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(result);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

                int bulk;
                InputStream inputStream = event.getFile().getInputstream();
                while (true) {
                  bulk = inputStream.read(buffer);
                  if (bulk < 0) {
                         break;
                         }
                  fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bulk);
                  fileOutputStream.flush();
                  }

                  fileOutputStream.close();
                  inputStream.close();

                  FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("OK",
                      event.getFile().getFileName() + " was upload.");
                  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

                  } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                  FacesMessage error = new FacesMessage("Can't upload!");
                  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, error);
                  }
        }
```

my problem is when i upload a picture type png such as aaa.png, it can upload on server but it not rename, after upload aaa.png and i re-upload this picture(aaa.png) it can change name but it have 2 file one is aaa.png and one is macback.png

What's wrong in my code?

Thank you !

Comment: so you want to just end up with `bg.png` and `macback.png` with no `aaa.png` at all, correct?

Comment: Hello Beemer , i want rename file upload aaa.png to macback.png , code below i just test it can change from image on server to another name and then change image upload to macback.png. If i work well i will delete bg.png on server

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you are trying to do:

1. When you upload a file, you want to call it macback.png, not its original file name.
2. When you upload a second file, you want to rename macback.png to bg.png first, then save the uploaded file as macback.png.

If that is the case, first you need to test for the existence of the macback.png file and rename it if it exists. Then you create a File object for the macback.png file and open a FileOutputStream to that file to write the uploaded file to.

Something like this:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    ExternalContext extContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    File result = new File(extContext.getRealPath("//admin//images") + "//macback.png");
    if(result.exists()) {
        result.renameTo(new File(extContext.getRealPath("//admin//images")+"//bg.png"));
    }

    try {
        File targetFile = new File(extContext.getRealPath("//admin//images") + "//macback.png" );

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        int bulk;
        InputStream inputStream = event.getFile().getInputstream();
        while (true) {
            bulk = inputStream.read(buffer);
            if (bulk < 0) {
                break;
            }
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bulk);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
        }

        fileOutputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("OK",
        event.getFile().getFileName() + " was upload.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        FacesMessage error = new FacesMessage("Can't upload!");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jason, but it not what i want, my problem is when i upload picture A, it can upload on server but it not rename, i must re-upload picture A one again, it mean with picture A(2) it can rename to macback.png and it exist picture A too, it have 2 picture A, one is A.png and other it rename to macback.png, my problem is why first picture can't rename? why second picture can rename to macback?

Comment: Do you want the first picture A to rename to macback.png or the second picture A(2) to rename to macback.png?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let's see if I got it this time:

1. You want the first A.png to save as A.png.
2. The second time A.png is uploaded, you want the first A.png to be renamed to macback.png and the second A.png to be stored as A.png.

If that's the case, try this:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    ExternalContext extContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    File result = new File(extContext.getRealPath("//admin//images") + "//" + event.getFile().getFileName());
    if(result.exists()) {
        result.renameTo(new File(extContext.getRealPath("//admin//images")+"//mackback.png"));
    }

    try {
        File targetFile = new File(extContext.getRealPath("//admin//images") + "//" + event.getFile().getFileName() );

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        int bulk;
        InputStream inputStream = event.getFile().getInputstream();
        while (true) {
            bulk = inputStream.read(buffer);
            if (bulk < 0) {
                break;
            }
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bulk);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
        }

        fileOutputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("OK",
        event.getFile().getFileName() + " was upload.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        FacesMessage error = new FacesMessage("Can't upload!");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is you are trying to rename `result` to `f1` too early. At the point where you are calling `result.renameTo(f1)` you have not yet created the file referenced by `result` so the rename has no effect. You cannot rename a file before it exists on disk.

Now, you don't really need to rename `result`. Since you have not created the file, you can simply use `f1` as the argument to `FileOutputStream` instead of `result`.