# Generate hash value of an image selected from gallery for uploading with a unique name onto server?

Tags: java, android, image, hash, upload

I want to upload image to server with a unique name, how do i do that ?i want to use hash value generator for doing the same,
also how do i rename that file with the hash value so that i can uniquely identify it?
Thanks in advance guys!!

Answer (score 0):

First look at this for getting the hash of the file [Getting a File's MD5 Checksum in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304268/getting-a-files-md5-checksum-in-java).

Then look at this to rename your file [rename file after file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141348/rename-file-after-file-upload)

Hope that helps.